# fire off a function from another MC

Tags: function, actionscript, movieclip

I am trying to trigger a function from inside my "column" MC  via an eventListener from my "checkBoxes" MC. Is it even possible or should I look a different way?

my "column" MC code:

```
act_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, actPoint);
function actPoint(m:MouseEvent){
cA.height = cA.height + 10;
var clickSound:pointPlus = new pointPlus ();
clickSound.play(0,1);
if(cA.height == 200){
act_btn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, actPoint);
}
}
```

and this is the code from my "checkBoxes" MC:

```
cbPlus_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, actPoint);
```

As you can see, I added "actPoint" function to two different eventListeners...
...and of course, it`s not working  :(

Comment: I'm not 100% sure from your description what it is you're trying to do. Is that function on a frame within your column movieclip and you're trying to execute it when the user clicks the checkbox (cbPlus_btn)?

Comment: there is a "column" MC with the code I provided above. When I click on the button nested in the "column" MC, it triggers the actPoint function in the very same "column" MC.  Then there is another movie clip "checkBoxes", which contains check boxes. What I`m trying to achieve here is, when somebody checks a checkBox in the "checkBoxes"MC and clicks OK, the actPoint function would be triggered. I don`t know if it is possible to assign two event listeners within two different MCs to one function...so that`s what I`m asking  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign as many event listeners as you want to the same function. The key (and I think this may be your problem) is that the function you want to set as the listener has to be visible from the context in which you're trying to do so.

I think your problem is that you're not actually referencing the `actPoint` method within your column `MovieClip` when you try to create the click listener on the check box (if you post any error messages you're seeing in the console we may be able to confirm this).

Assuming the check box is created in the same scope as the column `MovieClip`, and assuming it has an instance name, you should be able to solve your issue by changing the code which adds the event listener on the check box to the following:

```
// Reference the method via the MovieClip instance which contains it
// Assumes column MovieClip has an instance name of columnMC
cbPlus_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, columnMC.actPoint);
```

Comment: It`s still not working :(  My columnMC has an instance name "c1", but that doesn`t matter that much.The "c1"MC is located at the stage and contains the code I posted at the very beginning of this thread.Lying next to my "c1"MC, also on the stage, is my "checkBoxes"MC and within it I put your suggested code and I changed the "columnMC" to "c1":  Looks like this:                                                   cbPlus_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, c1.actPoint);      function c1.actPoint(m:MouseEvent):void{trace("somestuff")} It gives:error1084:SyntaxErrorExpecting leftparen before dot.

Comment: The code I posted above (updated with the correct instance name of course) should be on a frame on the main timeline (at the same level as your column and checkbox movieclips). If you put the code inside the checkbox the column clip and it's methods will not be visible to it. Also, your dummy function declaration in the above comment is not valid (that's what's throwing the error). It shouldn't matter though, because we're trying to assign the listener to the method in the column clip.